# Exporting QGIS attributes form

Tags: qgis-3

I just completed a tree localization project on QGIS with the Mergin interface. I now have a map, a photo folder, and my spreadsheet with all my entities. I would like, if possible, to export the form view of the entity attribute table. which is perfect because it gives a sheet of each tree with the photo and these characteristics. If it's possible. I read that the cReport extension can do this but it seems that it is no longer compatible with my recent version of QGIS.

Comment: Hi, your question needs to be in English on this site and the use of all-caps writing is considered as shouting and considered quite rude.

Comment: I think you might be searching the [report](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/create_reports.html?highlight=report#creating-a-report) function?